# Is there a way, in html, to refer to the domain of a website without actually knowing it?

Tags: html

For example, I want a link to take the viewer to a folder on the website

`<a href = "http://www.Example.com/goToThisFolder"> Click here to go to this folder </a>`

But now I want to make it so that other developers can use my code on their website without having to personally edit it. Is there a way for me to reference the "http://www.Example.com" without actually knowing what the domain is?

Comment: You can't do this with HTML, but you can with Javascript or server-side with, say. PHP. You could perhaps use relative paths which imply the current domain, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to make a *relative* link, i.e. a link relative to the current URL or domain, simply leave out the domain:

```
<a href="foo.html">always goes to foo.html in the same folder as this document</a>
<a href="/foo.html">always goes to /foo.html in the same domain</a>
```

The same way you can also make a *protocol relative* URL:

```
<a href="//example.com/..">goes to https://.. if current page is https, otherwise http</a>
```